# Binary tree in Eiffel

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree, eiffel

I am trying to create a program to create a binary tree using recursive methods, but I'm having a problem.

In my class `MYNODE`, I'm including us left and right, however they can be null (Void). Here is the code, could someone help me?

```
class
    MYNODE
create
    make
feature
    name: STRING
    left: MYNODE
    right: MYNODE
    setname(n:STRING) do
        name:= n
    end
    setleft(i:MYNODE) do
        left:=i
    end
    setright(i:MYNODE) do
        right:=i
    end
    make do
        create nameme.make (80)
    end
end
```

And my Main Class:

```
class
    MAIN
create
    make
feature
    root : MYNODE
    node: MYNODE
    build_tree() do
        io.put_string ("Name: ")
        io.read_line
        node.setname(io.last_string)
        insert(node)
    end
    insert(no,al:MYNODE) do
        if no.name<al.name then
            if no.left = Void then
                no.setleft(al)
            else
                insert(no.left,al)
            end
        else
            if no.right = Void then
                no.setright(al)
            else
                insert(no.right,al)
            end
        end
    end
    make do
        create root.make()
        create node.make()
        build_tree()
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are having trouble compiling this code because the attributes are attached and thus need to be initialized before use. In order to allow `Void`, you need to declare the attributes `left` and `right` detachable, that is to say:

```
left, right: detachable MYNODE
```

Comment: Looks like a non-obvious default (being `attached`).